# MySQL, understanding SQL query behavior

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple MySQL table:

```
|   id   |   sid   |    date    | 
+--------+---------+------------+
| 1      | 1       | 2013-12-01 |
+--------+---------+------------+
| 3      | 2       | 2013-12-17 |
+--------+---------+------------+
| 4      | 1       | 2013-12-17 |
+--------+---------+------------+
| 5      | 1       | 2013-12-18 |
+--------+---------+------------+
```

I need group this table by sid field and get records with max id for each sid with correct date. I try below code:

```
SELECT MAX(id), date FROM my_table GROUP BY sid
```

But the date field is incorrect, for example I get date 2013-12-01 with id 5 as a result.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What are your desired results?

Comment: Get max id with correct date, in this example I would like to get id 5 with date 2013-12-18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way standard SQL is defined (at least up to ansi 1992, others will correct me), any field of your SELECT clause must be included in your group by condition. [Mysql allows you to not do so, but that is why it is confusing: the results are not as you expect]

Your query should then be:

```
SELECT MAX(id), date FROM my_table GROUP BY sid, date
```

But in this case, clearly this is not what you want. Your requirement is to get the date corresponding to the `MAX(id)` for each `sId`.

You have to isolate each part of the algorithm in different queries.

1 - get the max id for each sid:

`SELECT MAX(id) AS id, sid FROM my_table GROUP BY sid`

2 - get the date corresponding to the max of ids for each `sid`:

`SELECT date FROM my_table WHERE sid = X AND id = Y`

3 - join these 2 queries using an `INNER JOIN` or more shortly, a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT m.sid, m.id, m.date
FROM my_table m
    JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id, sid FROM my_table GROUP BY sid) t
        ON t.sid = m.sid AND m.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a join:

```
SELECT a.id, a.date
FROM foo a
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM foo GROUP BY sid) b ON a.id = b.max_id
```